# How can i change the edit mode of a cell in my Gridex Janus Table

Tags: c#, janus, gridex

I'm trying to create a Janus gridex which every cell has different edit mode.

For instance, one cell will be comboBox edit mode and the second one will be free text

How can it be done?

Thanks in advance,

Oz.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set each columns EditType to custom. Then hook onto the InitCustomEdit and EndCustomEdit events.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno for sure, but I'd bet you'll need to set the EDITMODE for the column, then control the ROW property thru code in the BEFORECOLUPDATE, or AFTERCOLUPDATE event to return to the correct cell if the user tries to exit the cell.

This would also mean you need to track the condition of the data in that particular cell, then allow the user to exit that cell when the edit is complete...